# How do I disable the right click on my Samsung Series 9 trackpad?

Tags: touchpad, mouse-click

Every time I click in the bottom right region on my trackpad, it's interpreted as a right click. This is annoying me to no end.

I looked through the mouse settings in Control Panel, but there seems to be no option to disable this feature there. Anyone know how I can disable this feature?

I'm using Windows 8 btw.

Comment: I dont know if you can disable it but can you change which action performs the right-click? For instance I think the default action is two fingered tap.. can you change it to a three fingered tap or some other action and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 8):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Enter `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Look for the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Elantech\SmartPad`
4. Change to `0` the value of the following properties:

   - `ClickPad_RightCorner_Click_Func`
   - `ClickPad_LeftCorner_Click_Func`
5. Restart your computer

Note both bottom right and bottom left click of the touchpad will be (left click)  now the only way to right click will be 2 finger tap or 2 finger click (thats only if u set that up in control panel under touchad or mouse properties depending on which elan version you have.)

Doing all this makes your touchpad exactly like a macbook pro

If your wondering why a 0 as the value is because thats left click, 1 is right click 2 is middle click, if u wanna play around with some of the settings just be careful, im not responsible for u screwing your mouse up

Answer (score 1):

You should install your touchpad drivers (i. e. Synaptics), not the ones that came with Windows 8 installation. Manufacturer's drivers usually include a utility program which allows turning off such things as right click on the corner of touchpad, etc. From there you will find your way easily, but it really depends on the utility program, so I can only suggest this much. I think this is easier than Windows solution. After disabling it, you can remove the utility program from startup as the settings will remain in effect.